# Capybara broken after upgrade: How can I handle clicking a link like in the case below

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara, geckodriver

`click_link('Click Me')` won’t work on

```
<a href="#">
<h1>Click Me</h1>
</a>
```

A case like above was passing until I upgraded capybara to 3.3. 
Context:
In gemfile:

```
   gem 'capybara', require: false
   gem 'capybara-accessible', '0.1.10', require: false
   gem 'capybara-firebug', require: false
   gem 'capybara', '~> 3.3', require: false
   gem 'capybara-screenshot', require: false
   gem 'cucumber', '~> 3.1', require: false
   gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.5'
```

gecko driver: version 0.20.1
firefox: version 60

Comment: What is the exact error you get now? What version of Capybara did you upgrade from? Are you sure it's actually on the page you think it is?

Comment: Also, have you configured Capybara to only do exact text matching?